# Using an indeterminate progress bar with a listview

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am using http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html as a reference.
I am trying to use an Indeterminate ProgressBar in a ListView,when I use:

```
    ProgressBar pb=new ProgressBar(this);
```

As the Android ListView training guide suggests,I try:

```
    pb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
```

Eclipse says this is an illegal constructor for LayoutParams.

Also,

```
    pb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

is considered illegal...

I have also tried:

```
    list_book.setEmptyView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_progress, (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content),true));
 list_book.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.layout_row,c,new String [] {BookDatabase.NAME,BookDatabase.AUTHOR,BookDatabase.PUBLISHER},new int[]{R.id.ltxt_name,R.id.ltxt_author,R.id.ltxt_pub}));
```

And layout_progress looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >
     <ProgressBar 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:indeterminate="true"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:src="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
    />
<TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="Loading Please Wait..."/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

If the above code can be used what would I pass as root view and should I attach my progressbar to root?
Code works just fine without the ProgressBar.

So,what is the correct way of doing this?

Also,there is an error in this line of code:

```
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

SOLVED this one:need to use

```
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself.I used a ProgressDialog within an AsyncTask.

```
   ProgressDialog dialog; 
   private class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Uri,Void,Cursor>        
   {
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
      dialog=new ProgressDialog();
      dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
      dialog.setMessage("Loading list of stuff");
    }
    //doInBackground goes here...
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
    {
      //load elements into the ListView by setting it's adapter
       dialog.dismiss(); 
    }
```

This will cause an error that says:

```
    has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e75f40   that was originally added here
```

So,you must dismiss the ProgressDialog in the onPause method just in case onPostExecute is not reached.

```
    protected void onPause()
    {
       if(dialog!=null)
          dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're using the wrong LayoutParams class.

Look at your imports at the top of your file.  You must be importing a specific static LayoutParams type (e.g. `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`)  Not all LayoutParams classes are equal, and the class you're trying to instantiate may not have the constructor you are trying to use.

Is your view's intended parent a `FrameLayout`?  Right now, I'd wager you'd like to use the [`FrameLayout.LayoutParams constructor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html#FrameLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20int%29), which takes a third int argument to specify `Gravity`.  But your import is specifying a class that doesn't have an (int, int, int) constructor (e.g. `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` or `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`).  So the compiler complains.

EDIT: For your second block, I believe you are missing a parenthesis.  Otherwise that looks fine to me.  (Again, assuming you're importing the right LayoutParams type.

`pb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); //two parens here to close`

I usu like to be explicit about what LayoutParams class I'm using, to avoid these kinds of mistakes:

`new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER)`

Comment: The intended parent of the ProgressBar is the ListView itself... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: like 'getListView().setEmptyView(progressBar);' also,trying the second one with the corrected syntax did not rectify the error